# R: nls singular gradient but when converged then strange summary

Tags: r

I am trying to fit an exponential decay model with nls. For some data sets works fine for some other I do have the singular gradient problem. I played with the initial guess and then it converges:

```
al<- c(1.000000000, -0.191323992,  0.033160155,  0.098588015,  0.091868322,
       0.093882227, -0.008586943,  0.111179350,  0.114696305, -0.219874647,
      -0.058803866,  0.064467078,  0.012330649, -0.121760137, -0.028633566,
      -0.166431701, -0.129571514, -0.227254377,  0.189324908,  0.158551556,
       0.035583227,  0.068326222, -0.019393207, -0.058901557,  0.278201324,
      -0.186608434, -0.065429683, -0.149088734,  0.125509557,  0.057595929,
       0.151851443,  0.163017250,  0.296895691,  0.161603269,  0.106648901,
       0.008832903)

dist<-c(0.00000,   21.70568,  106.26789,  207.77424,  272.99427,  344.35261,
      413.31444,  458.64773,  505.02554,  543.35691,  569.11492,  604.81217,
      650.79766,  694.61326,  732.70419,  770.36200,  815.77073,  866.19371,
      916.37255,  958.81687,  997.11661, 1040.33902, 1093.52611, 1153.57151,
     1210.58217, 1265.61952, 1334.84359, 1413.56687, 1495.18853, 1580.78396,
     1662.75520, 1767.75038, 1887.74513, 2009.35511, 2184.02066, 2888.08612)

nl<-nls(al~1*(exp(-dist/(ti))),data=ndat,start=list(ti=10),
lower=0.1,upper=10000,algorithm="port",control=list(warnOnly = TRUE),trace=T)

  0:    0.35937482:  10.0000
  1:    0.33103226: 0.100000
  2:    0.33103226: 0.100000
```

if initial ti =100 it doesn't but if I put ti=1000 then it does!! (first abnormal activity..)

lets check the summary (with the "converged" case of ti=10):

```
summary(nl)

Formula: al ~ 1 * (exp(-dist/(ti)))

Parameters:
    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|) 
ti 1.000e-01  1.171e+90       0        1

Residual standard error: 0.1375 on 35 degrees of freedom Algorithm
"port", convergence message: both X-convergence and relative
convergence (5)
```

And check the confidence interval now:

```
confint(nl) 
Waiting for profiling to be done...
    2.5%    97.5% 
      NA 532.2994
```

What happened with the Std. Error? I guess due to p and t values that the estimated parameter is totally insignificant? Should the ti=0 actually?
How it estimates the range of the ti within 95% confidence? shouldn't be ti +- 1.96*std error?

Answer (score 1):

You data does not support this model. Looking at the plot, `nl` is more or less randomly distributed around 0 for all values of `dist` other than 0, where it is 1. So expecting to fit an exponential decay model is unrealistic. `nls(...)` generates the best estimate based on your specification: t<sub>i</sub> is set to the lowest possible value, based on your specification in `lower=...`.

```
ndat <- data.frame(al,dist)
nl<-nls(al~1*(exp(-dist/(ti))),data=ndat,start=list(ti=10),
        lower=0.1,upper=10000,algorithm="port",
        control=list(warnOnly = TRUE),trace=T)
plot(ndat$dist,ndat$al)
lines(ndat$dist,predict(nl), col="red",lty=2)
```

[image]

The standard error in t<sub>i</sub> is so large because the estimate is very poor.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Well the first I thought was that the model just can not be fitted. But still I would expect that I can get an exponential decay with a vast decay though. Without the lower limit complains again for singular gradient and then it doesn’t matter the initial guess.

Comment: It *does* have a "vast decay". The decay coefficient is 1/ti, or 100, which is as large as it can be given that you set the lower limit for ti to 0.1.